# MVC or Webservices + jQuery

Tags: jquery, web-services, model-view-controller

I'm some kind of newbie with MVC but have been working with WS over 4 years.

I have to build a reporting web application (some grids and some graphics) and I want to know what is the best way to build it. This application needs to be accessible from many different browsers/devices (smartphone, iPad, desktop-win, desktop-mac, etc.) and mantain persistence, so I was thinking about a UI for non javascript devices and another working with jQuery, both consuming a webservice.

On the other hand, I've read about MVC and in multiple sites says I can do this creating a few methods returning the entire view  ([Khaja's Response](http://bit.ly/QkgQ8P)) and anothers working with jQuery.

I want to know your opinion about this so I can take the better decision with this.

Thank you.

Comment: You need to tell us more about what kind of web application you're using.  I'm confused by your post because jQuery is a front-end related framework, while an MVC is a type data-structure used in most modern day server-side frameworks (i.e. Ruby on Rails, Django for Python).

Comment: Are you talking about MVC design pattern? Or are you, just like people who refer to IE as "the internet", talking about the ASP.NET MVC framework ?

Comment: I'm building an application capable to mantain users and display reports with some kind of data grids.

I'm refering to the MVC design pattern.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Jorge, if you prefer dealing with services\APIs then you should try using **Web API**. See: http://www.asp.net/web-api

It's actually an added feature set of MVC4. It has great support for creating RESTful Json based APIs. Which would work nicely with jquery

Here's a great video worth watching: http://channel9.msdn.com/Shows/Web+Camps+TV/Dan-Roth-Takes-Us-on-a-Deep-Dive-into-Web-API

Also, here's a nice sample project using Web API + jquery: http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/Contact-Manager-Web-API-0e8e373d/

Answer (score 0):

Definitely you can do that in MVC. It is not clear that whether you want an editable grid(perhaps not as you are doing reporting service) or not.... anyway in the model section of mvc make return object of Table type or List type, which you can show in your view section. You can create views from your Model itself automatically.
for images, if paths are stored in the database use the following syntax

```
<img src= "@Url.Content(Model.PictureLocation)" alt="IMAGES" />
```